# List folders from a directory which id is not a specific value in Google Drive API v3 and C#

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I want to get list of sub-folders from folder id but except by specific ids (not all of them). I meant I want to get children which id is not in the list I provide

```
 public async Task<FileListData> ListWithoutIds(string id, int itemsPerPage = 10, string nextPageToken = null, bool onlyFolders = false, bool onlyFiles = false, string[] excludeIds = null)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id))
  {
    throw new ArgumentException($"'{nameof(id)}' cannot be null or whitespace", nameof(id));
  }

  var request = PrepareListRequest(itemsPerPage, nextPageToken);
  request.Q = $"'{id}' in parents";
  if (onlyFolders)
  {
    request.Q = $"{request.Q} and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'";
  }
  else if (onlyFiles)
  {
    request.Q = $"{request.Q} and not mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'";
  }

  if (excludeIds?.Length > 0)
  {
    request.Q = $"{request.Q} {string.Join(" ", excludeIds.Select(e => $"and not id='{e}'"))}";
  }

  return FileListData.From(await request.ExecuteAsync()); // here I got 400 error
}
```

and

```
private FilesResource.ListRequest PrepareListRequest(int itemsPerPage, string nextPageToken, string[] specificFields = null)
{
  var request = driveService.Files.List();
  request.PageSize = itemsPerPage;
  request.SupportsAllDrives = true;
  request.IncludeItemsFromAllDrives = true;

  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nextPageToken))
  {
    request.PageToken = nextPageToken;
  }

  if (specificFields?.Length > 0)
  {
    var fields = $"{string.Join(",", specificFields)}";
    request.Fields = $"nextPageToken, files({fields.Trim(',')})";
  }
  else
  {
    request.Fields = "nextPageToken, files";
  }
  return request;
}
```

The query executed looks like:

```
'parentFolderId' in parents and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and not id='Child1Id' and not id='Child2Id' and not id='Child3Id'
```

And I got 400 error.

How to achive that ?

Comment: Q parameter is very limited thats not something you can do in a single request. I would loop over your children and build up the response you are looking for.  if you check the documentation you will notice you cant search on id at all https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-search-terms

Comment: I'm not using v2, I use v3

Comment: It's the same for v3: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-search-terms

Comment: The only difference between drive v2 and drive v3 is that its name and not title.  

Comment: So they are not interested to do such operations

Comment: Google returns the data you need to filter it yourself. If your worried about performance check out the fields parameter it will limit the data returned. MIght speed things up a little but its not going to help your quota.

Comment: You cannot really exclude results from a list before obtaining those results - you need to do it posteriorly as I tried to explain in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The query funcitonality of the Drive API is quite limited, the id of the list results is not a possible [query term](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-search-terms).

You need to reconstruct the logic of your code.

- First get a list of your folders with the query `'parentFolderId' in parents and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'` and set `Fields` to `files/id`
- Subsequently implement programmatically a filter to substract from the total id list the ids you want to exclude.